# displaying an image full screen in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

> The following program works the for the first .jpg  in the directory.
>   When called the second time it gets a "_tkinter.TclError: image
>   "pyimage2" doesn't exist" exception. Why does it get the error? Is
>   there a way to reuse the first image rather than creating a second?

import sys, os
    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        import Tkinter
        tkinter = Tkinter 
    else:
        import tkinter
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk

```
def showPIL(pilImage):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    root.focus_set()
    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: (e.widget.withdraw(), e.widget.quit()))
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.configure(background='black')
    imgWidth, imgHeight = pilImage.size
 # resize photo to full screen 
    ratio = min(w/imgWidth, h/imgHeight)
    imgWidth = int(imgWidth*ratio)
    imgHeight = int(imgHeight*ratio)
    pilImage = pilImage.resize((imgWidth,imgHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)   
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    print(image)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=image)
    root.mainloop()

names = os.listdir("E://Users//scott//Pictures")
print(names)
for file in names:
    print(file)
    if file[-4:] == ".jpg":
        file=Image.open("E://Users//scott//Pictures//"+file)
        showPIL(file)
```

> Here is the console output. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "e:\Users\scott\Documents\Python\image test.py", line 36, in 
>       showPIL(file)   File "e:\Users\scott\Documents\Python\image test.py", line 27, in showPIL
>       imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=image)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2486, in
>   create_image
>       return self._create('image', args, kw)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2477, in _create
>       *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
>   _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
>
> > > >

Answer (score 1):

> > after searching around I discovered that the first problem that tkinter.Tk() was being called multiple times whereas it must be called
> >     only once so I moved it out of the showPIL function and  into the
> >     initialization.  The next problem is that mainloop blocks so I
> >     replaced it with the combination of root.update_idletasks() and
> >     root.update(). The following works as I expect and need:

```
import sys, os
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # the tkinter library changed it's name from Python 2 to 3.
    import Tkinter
    tkinter = Tkinter #I decided to use a library reference to avoid potential naming conflicts with people's programs.
else:
    import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.focus_set()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
canvas.pack()
canvas.configure(background='black')


def showPIL(pilImage):
    imgWidth, imgHeight = pilImage.size
 # resize photo to full screen 
    ratio = min(w/imgWidth, h/imgHeight)
    imgWidth = int(imgWidth*ratio)
    imgHeight = int(imgHeight*ratio)
    pilImage = pilImage.resize((imgWidth,imgHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)   
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=image)
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
#    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: (e.widget.withdraw(), e.widget.quit()))


names = os.listdir("E://Users//scott//Pictures")
print(names)
for file in names:

    print(file)
    if file[-4:] == ".jpg":
        file=Image.open("E://Users//scott//Pictures//"+file)
        showPIL(file)

        time.sleep(5)
```